# Como obter a largura do scroll criado pelo Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Ao criar uma tabela e habilitar o `Datatable` na mesma, caso a largura da tabela seja maior que a tela onde está sendo exibida o plugin cria automaticamente um `scroll` lateral. Na documentação eles chamam de **[ScrollX(horizontal)](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)**.

Então, possuo o seguinte problema:

Foi criado um *Javascript* para que de acordo com a movimentação do mouse em **X** a tabela se movimenta, facilitando a usabilidade do usuário, com isso não estou conseguindo obter a **largura total da tabela** para implementar no *Javascript*.

Gostaria de um auxílio para que consiga obter esse valor e assim deixar o código mais eficiente, pois hoje foi o valor foi setado manualmente na largura da tabela.

Abaixo o `código` utilizado para que funcione o `scroll` através do mouse:

```
**
     * Função que realiza o processo para fazer o scroll na tabela de acordo com a posição do mouse,
     * é aplicado na classe table-responsive, portanto todas as tabelas que possuirem essa classe será aplicado.
     */
    if (jQuery.browser.mobile === false) {

        var $gal = $('.table-responsive');

        if ($gal.length > 0) {

            var galW = $gal.outerWidth(true),
            // É adicionado o valor de 450 pois não consegui pegar o tamanho do scroll pelo JS...
            // quando é utilizado o table-responsive não foi possível obter o valor do scroll.
                galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth + 450,
                wDiff = (galSW / galW) - 1,
                mPadd = 60,
                damp = 20,
                mX = 0,
                mX2 = 0,
                posX = 0,
                mmAA = galW - (mPadd * 2), // the mousemove available area
                mmAAr = (galW / mmAA); // get available mousemove didderence ratio

            $gal.mousemove(function (e) {

                mX = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
                mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
            });

            setInterval(function () {
                posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"
                $gal.scrollLeft(posX * wDiff);
            }, 5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Henrique, você poderia editar sua pergunta adicionando o código que implementou para obter uma resposta mais rápida.

Comment: Claro, desculpe vou realizar a alteração agora mesmo.